# Preventing the "Indirect Lighting" setting in Blender Internal from making the entire rendered image black

Tags: rendering, light

I'm currently working on a 3D scene in Blender 2.71. It has a mesh landscape. For the sky, I use a shadeless UV sphere with shadow deactivated. It also has a base in the center where most of the detail is located. Inside the base I have several meshes with an emit value given to them so that they act as artificial lighting (using Indirect Lighting). In order to make them actually *emit* light, I set the "Gather" setting to "Approximate" under the "World" tab of the "Properties" panel.

However when I look at the rendered view of my scene, the entire rendered image goes black (erratically when I look at it from different angles). I have tried removing certain items in the scene, but only deactivation of "Indirect Lighting" fixes the problem.

How do I keep the "Indirect Lighting" setting active, but prevent it from causing the entire rendered image to be black?

EDIT: I noticed that when the problem happened again recently, it stayed black from every angle, but the sky stayed visible (even though "cast shadows" is deactivated on the sky object).

EDIT-2: Here are some screenshots of the problem:
[image: Pic 1][image: Pic 2]

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of rendered image and what happens when you "look at it from different angles" (also a version of .[blend could be uploaded](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/))? That sounds like a bug but probably isn't. Are you sure that looking from different directions your viewpoint doesn't become located inside any object ?

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer a problem after upgrading to Blender 2.76b.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23605)

Comment: @PGmath I think this is fine as an answer, despite being rather short.  Especially since it's the OP answering